# Dynamic date range based a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I have a range of cells where US federal holidays are stored. The formula below then calculates a date 21 workdays out. Is it possible to have a dynamic date for the federal holidays. So I don't have to change them every year. O290-O310 is where the dates are stored.

```
=WORKDAY(A305,21,$O$290:$O$310)
```

Comment: it may not be a matter of changing the formula referring to where the dates are stored, but changing the way dates are actually stored.  Ie did you store 2016/07/04 as a holiday, or did you store is as say =date(Year(now()),07,04)?  and while that is one way to roll the date forward, it may not be the best way.  Also, if Christmas is on the weekend, do you get Friday or the Monday as a holiday and how is that determined?  and do you have holidays such as the third Friday in May that really are not a fixed date either?

Comment: The only fixed dates are Martin Luther King day (Third Monday In January), Washington's Birthday (Third Monday in February), Memorial Day (Last Monday in may), Labor Day (First Monday in September), Thanksgiving (4th Thursday in November) These Holidays float,If they fall on Saturday, (Friday is observed), if they fall on Sunday (Monday is observed): New years, Columbus Day, Veterans day, Christmas Day. July 4th is observed on the actual day, except if it falls on the weekend.

Comment: so now you need a way to figure out when those days are based on the year you are dealing with and save those in your range of set holidays.  that way they will update or be dynamic

Comment: They are stored as MM/DD/YYYY. Fixed dates 2017: 01/16/2017 (king), 02/20/2017 (Washington), 05/29/2017 (Memorial), 09/04/2017 (Labor), 11/23/2017 (thanksgiving). Floating dates: 01/02/2017 (New Years), 10/09/2017 (Columbus), 11/10/201 (veterans), 12/25/2017 (Christmas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work if you are only dealing with checking dates in a giving year,  if you are looking at calculating date spanning multiple years with the WORKDAY formula, you will need to either repeat the list adding +1 to the year in the function, or you will need to develop a different function for counting workdays and that would probably entail some VBA.

What you need to do is work out the logic on how the dates are figured out and store those calculated values in your sheet.  Now assuming you have a date somewhere in your sheet or you refer to the year someone in your sheet that you will be dealing with, you can try the following.  I will develop the logic for 3rd Monday in January.  you can then use this though process to develop your own method for coming up with similar holidays.  Take a look at the various built in date manipulation formulas built into excel such as DATE, YEAR, MONTH, DAY, WEEKDAY, TODAY, NOW, EOMONTH, etc.  they may be of great help to you.

### Dealing with dates that fall on X day or week of the month

I worked out the date using 7 steps in a table like this:

```
(A)                         |     (B)
Year                        |     2014
Weekday of 1st day of month |        4
Weekday number for Monday   |        2
Difference                  |       -2
3rd Monday                  |       21
Days from start of month    |       20
Target date                 | 14/01/20
```

Step 1)  Determine the year.

In cell B1 I hard coded this with a supplied 2014, but this could also be

```
=YEAR(Q10)
```

Where Q10 is some cell on your sheet with a date in the range you are working with of if you just have a year number say 2017 in a cell you could just point at that cell without the year.

Step 2)  Determine what day of the week the first day of the month is.

In order to do this we incorporate the DATE function imbedded in the WEEKDAY function.  Since we know were are dealing with January and the first day we can hard code that.  In B2 use:

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE(B1,1,1))
```

Step 3)  State the day of the week a Monday is.

This is important to do as depending no how your weekday function defines the start of the week, the day of the week that Monday is can vary.  since I did not date a change in the B2 formula we can supply the default value for Monday as 2.  so in B3:

```
=2
```

Step 4)  Find the difference between first weekday of month and Monday

The difference between the first weekday of the month and Monday need to be know in order to make an adjustment to the number of days since the start of the month the third Monday will fall.  In B4 use:

```
=B3-B2
```

Step 5)  Determine how many full weeks to third Monday.

If the difference is step 4 is negative or 0 you have another 21 days to work with, if its positive you need to work with 14 days. in B5 use:

```
=if(B4<=0,21,14)
```

Step 6)  Day of the month for 3rd Monday

So basically we need to ad B5 with B4, and that will tell us how many days from the start of the month the 3rd Monday will be.  In B6 use:

```
=B5+B4+1
```

Step 7)  Determine the date of 3rd Monday

We know the year, we know the month and now we know the day.  We take those three knowns and use the DATE function again. In B7 use:

```
=date(B1,1,B6)
```

Now if you want to back substitute that all into one formula in a single cell it would look something like:

```
=DATE(2014,1,IF(2-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014,1,1))<=0,21,14)+2-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014,1,1))+1)
```

Remember the 2014 would be from your spread sheet either using a cell with the year or using a cell with the date and using the YEAR() formula on that cell.

### Dealing with a holiday falling on a Saturday or Sunday

Again we need to refer to some cell in your spreadsheet with the year so I will again use Q10 as the example and we will assume a date of 2014/10/24.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=7,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,24),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26),DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)))
```

The formula checks first if the weekday is a Saturday.  W do this using a function that will return the day of the week  see step 2) above.  Which is this part from the equation above:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))
```

It will return a single integer 1 through 7 corresponding to the day of the week the date function results in, in this case.  If its a 1 we known its Sunday, if its 7 we know its Saturday.  So the check for saturday is:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=7
```

If WEEKDAY()=7 is true then we provides the date of the day before which is really just subtracting 1 from the date we were looking at.  We use this part of the formula to calculate that:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,24)
```

notice how I changed the day from 25 to 24.  An alternate way would be to recycle our date and make the computer do one more calculation using this formula:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)-1
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25-1)
```

That all sits in the TRUE portion of the if statement.  so if the date does not fall on Saturday then we wind up in the FLASE portion of the IF statement.  Here we check with a second IF for the date falling on a Sunday.  we use the same theory and process as we did for the Saturday check.

```
IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26),DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))
```

Placing an IF statement inside an IF statement is commonly referred to as "nesting".  This whole IF statement happens in the FALSE portion of the previous IF that checked to see if it was Saturday.   This time we checked for Sunday:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1
```

When this is true, then we need to increase the date by 1 day instead of decreasing it like was done for Saturday:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26)
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)+1
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25+1)
```

So that was the true portion of the Sunday check.  Logically speaking the only way to get to the FALSE portion of this nested IF statement is to fail the Saturday check and then fail the Sunday check.  Which means you do not need to go through and check if is the WEEKDAY comes out as 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6!  Its one of those by the process of eliminating Sunday and Satruday (1 and 7).  And if the date falls on Monday-Friday we dont need to change the date and can leave it just as is:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)
```

### HOLIDAY TABLE

This is a potential way you could layout a holiday table.

[image: Holiday Table]

little explanation here.  Row 3 and row 4 are the same information.  The difference is row 4 was formatted to only display the year.  Its actually a full date like row 3.  This is also very much different than enter the year as a number say 2014 or 2016.  Those are just numbers.  You can go any route you want, but you need to make your formulas work with what you are supplying them with.

In this example, I just used two holidays.  The third Monday in January example we worked out before and the Christmas case.  The holidays were layed out vertically beneath the year with all formulas referencing Q$4.  The year headers were copied to the right increasing the year by 1 for each column.  The holiday formulas were copied to the right.  As you do this they will automatically change the Q to R then S then T etc. so they will always be referencing the year above them.

Then when you use your workday formula, instead of referencing $Q$5:$Q$6 for this example you would reference $Q$5:$V$6.

The formula for advancing the date in R3 or R4 is:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Q4)+1,1,1)
```

Comment: NOTE the date will display in whatever your system settings are set to display provided the are an EXCEL date serial and not stored as text.

Comment: on a side not you could set up your holidays as a table.  in the header row you place the year.  in each subsequent row you place your formula for determining the date of the holiday. All the formulas only require the year as the input, you could then just copy the column underneath each year of the table.  Then when you use your workday formula you just refer to the entire table.  Without know what your spreadsheet is doing, hard to day what approach is the best approach, or if they even suit your needs.

Comment: Ed. Thank you. It appears that it will take some time to set this up, but I think it will be great once it is set up. I was wondering how February 29, is handled, since it occurs ever 4 years.

Comment: excel just handles it with its date calculation Try DATE(2016,2,17) and DATE(2017,2,29)  and see what displays.  Excel knows its straight calendar.  Its not so good with holidays as they vary from country to country.

Comment: Ed. Thanks for taking the time to teach me. I used the steps on a separate work sheet to figure out the steps. You made it so simple. Now that I understand the formula, I use the single cell formula.

Comment: "Give a man a fish, you feed him for a day.  Teach a man to fish, you feed him for a life time"  - someone else!  Another thing to remember, this is just one approach.  There are probably multiple approaches to achieving the same thing.

Comment: @Ed. 1 final question. After working with the formula, I realized that October, November & December will be in one year & January through September will be in the next year. Currently I am using `=YEAR((NOW()))`. Other than manually changing the year, do you have any advise, regarding a year formula? I need the first 3 moths to be static once we go into the new year.

Comment: @yes bare with me, got to take the dog for a walk AND have lunch AND run some errands.  In the mean time look at my second comment "On a side note..." as that is basically what I will do.  Just dont have the time to demo it and post a screenshot. at the moment

Comment: I was using the formula you provided for the floating dates, & it came up with the year 1905. Q4 in the formula is the year formula. Here is the formula. `=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,25))=7,DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,24),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,25))=1,DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,26),DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,25)))`. Could you explain what is happening? Sorry to be a pest.

Comment: I missed your "On a side note". That would resolve the split year issue. I am getting the wrong year answer when I try to go to another year. It comes back 1905. Let me work on it a little more & get back to you

Comment: The reason its giving you 1905 is that you probably have 2014 in as year.  This is number and not a date to excel.  you would need something like 2014/1/1.  HOWEVER, its much easier to drop the year from the formula and just use the DATE(Q4,12,24)  instead of DATE(YEAR(Q4),12,24)

Comment: On a completely unrelated now I was having some serious issue with name coming up in the formula.  I finally figured it out when moving through the formula 1 character at a time.  My cursor got stuck between the Q and the 4 for some reason.  There are some hidden character in there.  I retyped the address and everything started to work again.  Its the Q4 after the second weekday that was the problem

Comment: I found the problem. The current formula was based on just the current year. In order to calculate for the next year, I had to go to MM/DD/YYYY. Here is the formula for the next year: `=DATE(YEAR(Q3)+1,MONTH(Q3),DAY(Q3))`. Q3 is where the current date is stored.

Comment: that is how I incremented my date headers by 1 year  as I copied to the right. for the table I added to the answer.

Comment: I am having a problem with the target date part of the formula. `=DATE(S2,1,S8)`. It appears that the problem is with S2. That is where the year formula is located. Here is the formula: `=DATE(YEAR(Q3)+1,MONTH(Q3),DAY(Q3-1))`. Q3 is where the main date formula is housed. `=TODAY()` The S2 formula calculates the date a year out allowing for leap years.

Comment: Apologies Frank  I am a little lost at the moment.  I am assuming we are currently still dealling with the table of holidays.  How about we start a new question.  Title it something like how to build a holiday table.  Put a screen shot or build a table in the question of what you currently have.  Say it is a follow up to this question and we go from there.  I think I just need to start again with a fresh slate.

Comment: "##SUMMARY##"
The above formula is for static Federal Holidays If you follow the steps as stated above, it is very easy to set up.

Comment: Frank, at the bottom of YOUR question at the top of the page there should be a small grey edit button.  click that.  a small window will open up and has your orginal question in it.  Scroll to the bottom of that window then do your summary.