# Count Weekend Days Between Range Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a count of weekend days (WEEKDAY1 and WEEKDAY7) that occur within a range.  There are three excellent posts here on how to do it VBA style, but this is not an option here.  The range will not be more than a few weeks, but can cross the end of any given month.

An example:
21 September 2015 to 10 October 2015 (inclusive)
Count of weekend days = 5

Comment: If the first or last date in your range is a weekend day, you do want to include it, right ??

Comment: Yes please, I'll amend the post to clarify

Comment: does a holiday Monday or a holiday Friday count as part of your weekend day?

Comment: @Forward Ed I just assumed that calculating for Bank Holidays would be unfeasable, but if you can find a way that will be two gold stars as it will save me a ton of extra work.

Comment: asper Jeeped's link on the network functions there is an argument in there for holidays.  however in order to use that you would need to build a list of holiday dates.  Which that can be a challenge on its on as they vary from country to country.  Not impossible though.

Comment: @Paul what country would this spreadsheet before,  I just went through the process with another individual building a [holiday list for Federal Holidays in the US](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027791/dynamic-date-range-based-a-range-of-cells/37033386?noredirect=1#comment61694129_37033386)  and thanks to the help of Scott Craner can now figure out easter in a single cell should it be needed!  If you are interesting in building a list of holidays post a question about it.

Comment: @Forward Ed I'm in the UK and before I posted another question, I thought I'd look into things a bit.  I attempted to find out the rules for when Easter is set and Jesus Christ is it complicated.  Thanks for the link though, I hope that will prove fruitful.

Comment: It seems that the Easter Calc is not so bad after all.  The Year is in Cell D19, according to Wiki the formula for Easter Sunday is: =DOLLAR(("4/"&D19)/7+MOD(19*MOD(D19,19)-7,30)*14%,)*7-6

Comment: Yeah, easter is a messy one.  I asked Scott Craner if he was up for a challenge and if so give a one cell answer to calculate easter.  He did it from scratch in about twenty minutes.  Took me more than that just to get through the history on the calculation!  Glad you found a nice elegant solution  I assume that is good up to the year 2199.

Comment: Do you have boxing day in the UK?  they do not in the states, but they do in Canada.

Comment: Yes, we do have Boxing days (Dec 26).  If you are curious...https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.  I now have an horrific  formula for calculating is any given day is a bank holiday or a substitute bank holiday (if Boxing day is a Saturday for example) but it's 1006 chars long and I suspect the admins will get upset if I post that here.

Comment: [Calculate number of Sundays in the month](https://superuser.com/q/770639/241386)

Comment: @phuclv This is 3 and a half years old, but thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-48E717BF-A7A3-495F-969E-5005E3EB18E7) or [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28) function will give you the number of non-weekend days. Subtract this from the total days.

```
=(B1-A1)-NETWORKDAYS.INTL(A1, B1,1)+1
```

Comment: Thank you Jeeped.  Gold star.

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are in Column A1:A30, I would use a helper column containing

```
B1 = Weekday(A1,1)
```

Copied all the way down to B30. I would then use

```
Countif(A1:A30,1) + Countif(A1:A30,7)
```

to check for  Sunday and Saturday.