# building a holiday table using a formula

Tags: excel-formula

This is a follow up to the [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027791/dynamic-date-range-based-a-range-of-cells/37033386?noredirect=1#comment61694129_37033386).

[image: A screenshot of the work sheet in question.]

The only differences between the original formula & the one that is causing a problem is location AC3 is a static date & location S2 is dynamic. S2 houses a dynamic formula that allows for a leap year:

```
=DATE(YEAR(Q3)+1,MONTH(Q3),DAY(Q3-1))
```

Location Q3 refers to a basic date formula:

```
=TODAY()
```

I hope this helpful.

Comment: hey frank love the question, lets see what we can do to help! 8)  Did you scan a print out of your screen, or place it in something like a word document?  If so there is an easier way I can tell you about later.

Comment: Interesting to see where you have gone with developing your table.  Not what I was thinking but we will work with it.

Comment: How to post a screen capture with windows.  make your target the active window by clicking on it.  Press CTRL+PRINT SCREEN on your keyboard.  Go to you web browser and go to www.imgur.com.  In the top left corner click on the blue button.  Press CTRL+V  and a window will be added to the bottom.  Press start upload.  If you want to crop your image select edit.  If not use the direct link for copying and pasting the address to be included with your question/answer.

Comment: Having said that example data is always better than a picture. as pictures as not searchable or allow for cutting and pasting into other peoples spreadsheets for tinkering 8)

Comment: I would change your S1 formula to be `Date(year(Q3),1,1)` and your S2 formula to `Date(year(Q3)+1,1,1)`.  I would then change your formatting for the cell from Date to custom and make the custom format "yyyy".

Comment: What is your formula in S3 if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your formula in S9 to:

```
=Date(year(s2),1,S8)
```

The reason for this is Date is looking for 3 integers to be passed to it.  What you did was pass it a date in the place of a year number that really did not make sense to excel.  What you needed to send is:

```
=Date(2016,1,22)
```

What you sent was:

```
=Date(5/5/2016,1,22)
or more accurately
=Date(42496,1,22)
```

42496 is how excel stores a date.  What the year function does is strip the year part of the date and return it as an integer.

```
=Year(5/6/2016)
this really equates to
2016 'an integer
```

Hope that clarifies some things.

When you have all your formulas condensed down to a single cell and pointed at one year, consider arranging them as follows:

[image: Many years]

or

[image: 2 years only]

You should only need row 3 or row 4, which ever you prefer.  Also once you have one column of holidays set up, you should just be able to copy them to the right.

Comment: @Ed like usual you are on the mark with your answer.  I would not have been able to get as far as I have, if you did not take the time to teach me the steps. Should I post the steps I went through so other users can benefit?

Comment: @FrankM  I am not sure.  Might want to wait until you got everything sorted and working like you want.  OMG just looked at easter.  That is not an easy one!

Comment: @ed I am having a Monday vacation brain day. Could you explain to me how to convert what we have come up with into a single formula. I used what you saw to help me understand the formula & to check the single formula. Here is the old formula for dynamic holidays. `=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=7,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,24),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))`. Here is the old static formula `=1,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26 ),DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)))`. I am not concerned about Easter, because it is not a federal holiday.

Comment: Easter is an issue that has been going on for centuries...whole can of worms, but I digress.  Lets take a look at those two formulas and see if I can jump start the old noggin this morning.  is that static formula complete?

Comment: Ok frank, I am not sure if I answered your question or not, but I rewrote the section on a Saturday or Sunday holiday check section in the previous answer.  IF that does not help let me know, and it might be a case of starting a new follow up question.  Not the end of the world...more questions you ask the greater potential for building your rep which will allow you to do things like take part in chat rooms

Comment: I am trying to use a single formula for the static instead of 6 cells to use the calculations. I sent the original single formula, that you suggested as a base line.

Comment: Did the expanded explanation in the other question help?