# Using a dynamic single formula to calculate a date

Tags: excel-formula

This is a follow up to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37077640/building-a-holiday-table-using-a-formula/37080380?noredirect=1#comment61778583_37080380).

@ForwardED I am trying to convert your original single static formula into a single dynamic formula.

Unfortunately my employer's filters will let me up certain things to a hyperlink, but will not let me download or view from the same site. I am also trying to come up with a formula for floating dates.

Comment: Ok so I take it that the [expanded explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027791/dynamic-date-range-based-a-range-of-cells/37033386?noredirect=1#comment61694129_37033386) in the original question for the Sunday/Satruday did not work for you?

Comment: and so you do not get down voted, we may need to reword your question to something like... How to determine the weekday date of a fixed holiday for any year.  ie what is the date of the Christmas holiday when it falls on the weekend.?  or something like that.  This question that you have posted is more like a private discussion which is not going to help anyone else.

Comment: Let narrow down some terminology  3rd Monday in January is what type of holiday Floating, Fixed, Static, Dynamic etc.   having read the questions multiple times on different days I am getting lost in the naming convention.  So to clear things up, for this question, you are looking at a holiday like Christmas that has a fixed date in a year, or are we dealing with a holiday that is something like the 3 Monday in January?  or are we dealing with some other holiday?

Comment: There are certain fixed days that do follow on the third Monday in a month i.e. Martin Luther King day. I have kept that Monday as part of the formula, because I was able to get the formula to work even though there was no holiday on that date. So 3rd Monday is a fixed date. I am looking at a day that has a set day on  the calendar, but may not be observed on the day, because it falls on a weekend i.e. Christmas 2016 falls on Sunday but is observed as a federal holiday on Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a copy of the expanded explanation I gave on the original question.  I am not sure if you missed it or not.  It deals with holidays that have a set date like Christmas, 25th of December of every year.  However if it fall on a Saturday the time of work is the Friday and if it is on a Sunday the day off is the Monday.

### Dealing with a holiday falling on a Saturday or Sunday

Again we need to refer to some cell in your spreadsheet with the year so I will again use Q10 as the example and we will assume a date of 2014/10/24.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=7,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,24),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26),DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)))
```

The formula checks first if the weekday is a Saturday.  We do this using a function that will return the day of the week  See step 2) from the original question.  It is this part from the equation above:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))
```

It will return a single integer 1 through 7 corresponding to the day of the week the date function results in, in this case.  If its a 1 we known its Sunday, if its 7 we know its Saturday.  So the check for Saturday is:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=7
```

If WEEKDAY()=7 is true then we provides the date of the day before which is really just subtracting 1 from the date we were looking at.  We use this part of the formula to calculate that:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,24)
```

notice how I changed the day from 25 to 24.  An alternate way would be to recycle our date and make the computer do one more calculation using this formula:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)-1
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25-1)
```

That all sits in the TRUE portion of the if statement.  so if the date does not fall on Saturday then we wind up in the FLASE portion of the IF statement.  Here we check with a second IF for the date falling on a Sunday.  we use the same theory and process as we did for the Saturday check.

```
IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1,DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26),DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))
```

Placing an IF statement inside an IF statement is commonly referred to as "nesting".  This whole IF statement happens in the FALSE portion of the previous IF that checked to see if it was Saturday.   This time we checked for Sunday:

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25))=1
```

When this is true, then we need to increase the date by 1 day instead of decreasing it like was done for Saturday:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,26)
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)+1
or
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25+1)
```

So that was the true portion of the Sunday check.  Logically speaking the only way to get to the FALSE portion of this nested IF statement is to fail the Saturday check and then fail the Sunday check.  Which means you do not need to go through and check if is the WEEKDAY comes out as 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6!  Its one of those by the process of eliminating Sunday and Saturday (1 and 7).  And if the date falls on Monday-Friday we dont need to change the date and can leave it just as is:

```
DATE(YEAR(Q10),12,25)
```

And I realized I did not explain how the date function works, though I think I tried to in one of the previous questions...regardless!  DATE(arg1,arg2,arg3) requires three different arguments as integers or other functions that return integers.

- arg1 is the year so 2014, 1995, 1965 are all acceptable integers.  Also we could use YEAR(Q10),  where the cell Q10 holds the date of 2014/10/24.  In this case YEAR(Q10) would return 2014.
- arg2 is the month and needs to be an integer in the range of 1 to 12.  Again you can always use a formula that returns an integer in that range as well such as MONTH(Q10) which from our previous value of Q10 would return 10.
- arg3 is day and similar to the above it needs to be an integer. A formula such as DAY(Q10) would return a value of 24.

What this means is if we know what day a holiday is on we can force it to a date by supplying a set month and day, and letting the year be determined by a formula that supplies the year you are interested in.  So if you look at the last formula you can see we fixed the month at 12 and the day at 25.  They year will be determine from the year of the date supplied in cell Q10.

Comment: @ed  Thank you for that concise & through explanation. You are  a true gentleman.

Comment: What is the proper way of posting the complete set of formulas  to this question,so others don't have to dig to get the answers?

Comment: you could edit either your very first question or your very last question.  then ad the end of your question put 3 dashes --- with a blank line above and below.   After that type away and start with "##UPDATE##" or "##SUMMARY##"

Comment: "##SUMMARY##"
The above formula is for floating Federal Holidays. If your Fiscal year does not follow a calendar year, I would recommend that one cell for each year is used. if you follow the steps shown above it is very easy to set up.